# Installed magento 2.1 on windows but it is is giving many require js errors

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have installed `Magento 2.1` from web wizard installation but after installation It is giving require js errors and admin page is showing blank screen.

I tried deleting pub/static and var and then deployed but same problem again. Please help to resolve this issue.

[image]

**ERROR:**

ReferenceError: require is not defined

http://localhost/exassignment/pub/static/version1543493627/_requirejs/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js:626:1

Comment: add screen short

Comment: @AdarshShukla I have added the error text. As i can't take screen shot of console panel.

Comment: whats shown on frontend

Comment: @AdarshShukla updated question and i have screen shot of front end console. Please check.